Maven cannot resolve a kotlin library of .knm files
The first question is: what is a .knm file? I tried to google it, but all I could find is some issues about the idea not having highlight for .knm files. Also I am curious why the library has package structure like linkdata.package_dev...?
The second and the main question is: the maven cannot resolve the library. How can I fix it?

I have used this library with the gradle and it was fine.
I tried using other versions of the library with the same result.
I have a fresh installed 2024.2 community version, invalidate caches did nothing.
My pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenCentral</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>MainKt</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kotlin-telegram-bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-telegram-bot</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.inmo</groupId>
            <artifactId>krontab</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>


There is something wrong with your build setup. Please [edit] your question and provide the relevant parts of your build files.

@tyg I've added my pom.xml

um, nobody even knows what .knm files are?...

I don't know exactly but I guess that knm-files are Kotlin native and/or multiplatform compiled.
You need to reference the jvm-version of the library:
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.inmo</groupId>
    <artifactId>krontab-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

